# Keep iOS table section header view position when editing table rows

Tags: ios

When editing iOS table rows by swiping left, section header views positions are also moved to the left. Is there a way to keep the section header view position while editing table rows?

Comment: What do you mean? By default (on a Master-Detail Application) the section headings don't move, either swiping cells left or going into editing state by pressing the edit button..

Comment: @MichaelSand Oh really? Any example project that I can take a look at?

Comment: My results at https://www.dropbox.com/sh/53t52r9lp5defvl/AAD4gRnTOrLrkEIeTJoIUvK9a?dl=0 .Just create a new Xcode Project for Master-Detail. To give it sections --Change number of sections to 3 -- change number of rows to self.objects.count / 3 -- title for header in section to    return [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Section %li", (long)section];
--  and change the last line of insert new object to     [self.tableView reloadData];
//commenting:    [self.tableView insertRowsAtIndexPaths:@[indexPath] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationAutomatic];

Comment: @MichaelSand Thanks a lot for your help. But why do you share a movie instead of code? Anyway, I'll try what you told me. Thanks!

Comment: Added a movie because having trouble understanding what you mean, because what is in the movie is what you describe, and that is the default behavior if you create a "Master-Detail" project in Xcode.

Comment: @MichaelSand Confirmed that a "Master-Detail" project works fine. Thanks a lot for your help!

Comment: Hey, I wrote the comment as an answer, if you could mark it accepted that would be great.

Answer (score 1):

By default (on a Master-Detail Application) the section headings don't move, either swiping cells left or going into editing state by pressing the edit button.

To see this, create a new Xcode Project for Master-Detail. A quick way to give it sections:

1. Change `numberOfSections` to `return 3`
2. Change `numberOfRowsInSection` to `self.objects.count / 3`
3. Change `titleForHeaderInSection:` to return `[NSString stringWithFormat:@"Section %li", (long)section];`
4. Change the last line of insert new object to `[self.tableView reloadData]; //commenting: [self.tableView insertRowsAtIndexPaths:@[indexPath] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationAutomatic];`

You can see the result of this at [dropbox.com/sh/53t52r9lp5defvl/AAD4gRnTOrLrkEIeTJoIUvK9a?dl=0](http://dropbox.com/sh/53t52r9lp5defvl/AAD4gRnTOrLrkEIeTJoIUvK9a?dl=0) . Since this is the default behavior, something else must be causing the headers to slide.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this trick ,every section has rows have a empty section before. So just hide the current row section headers, but show the before section header.So when you manipulate the current row, but the before section will not be affected.

Comment: Or another way is create section header view as a normal table cell. But I'm looking for a simple solution.

Answer (score 0):

The problem was I was using UITableViewCell for viewForHeaderInSection instead of UITableViewHeaderFooterView. Using UITableViewHeaderFooterView fixes this issue. Big thanks to @MichaelSand !

Answer (score -1):

In **SWIFT2.0**:

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, viewForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> UIView? {
    let  headerView : UIView = UIView(frame: CGRectMake(0, 0, 704, 30)) //write frames as your requirement 

    headerView.backgroundColor = UIColor(red: 61/255, green: 133/255, blue: 167/255, alpha: 1)

    let headerLabel: UILabel = UILabel()
    headerLabel.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0,704, 30)
    headerLabel.backgroundColor = UIColor.clearColor()
    headerLabel.textAlignment = NSTextAlignment.Center
    headerLabel.font = UIFont.boldSystemFontOfSize(17)
    headerLabel.textColor = UIColor.whiteColor()
    headerLabel.text = "Section Header"
    headerView.addSubview(headerLabel)

    return headerView
}
```